# How to find a channel by name and create it if it does not exist in Discord.Net C#

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I want to search for a text channel and then create it if it does not exist.
I have this code that gets it by ID but if the channel does not exist, there is no ID. How can I create it if it does not exist searching the channel by name?

```
// here needs to be finding the channel etc.
ITextChannel logChannel = Context.Client.GetChannel(ChannelID) as ITextChannel;

If (!logChannel.Exists) 
{
     await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync("log");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search Channels with the power of Linq, and if you don't find the channel, you can create that way as you wrote above:

```
// find the channel if exists (by any criteria, in your case, check by the name)
var channel = Context.Guild.Channels.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "log");

if (channel == null) // there is no channel with the name of 'log'
{
    // create the channel
    var newChannel = await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync("log");

    // If you need the newly created channels id
    var newChannelId = newChannel.Id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, could you also provide a snippet of code to convert the name into a channel ID?

Comment: Just realized that it needs to be an ID to do stuff with it

Comment: I think I solved it ``var channelID = Context.Guild.Channels.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "blrp-log").Id;``

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Yes, almost. But when the `SingleOrDefault` returns `null` (when channel not found), that will cause an exception, because of the `.Id`. So you have to check this.